# Using crossfilter with dc.js and d3.js - how to get csv year data into date format?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I am trying to use a csv data source with a column titled "Year" to produce a bar chart using dc.js to create a crossfilter-based dashboard. I can't see how to get the Year into a usable date format. Is there anyone that can help?

I am using dc.js 1.2 with d3.v3.min.js

I tried adapting the main example but have no idea what the "e" comes from:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y");
var numberFormat = d3.format(".2f");

         data.forEach(function(e) {
            e.dd = dateFormat.parse(e.Year);
         });
```

I also tried this:

```
var dateYear = new Date(d.Year, 0);// The required 0, is for January
```

The variable is declared as:

```
var yearDimension = data.dimension(function(d){ return d3.time.year(d.dd);});
```

And I also tried this to give up on the date format completely and using an ordinal scale:

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
//.xUnits(d3.units.ordinal);
```

Declaring the variable as:

```
var yearDimension = data.dimension(function(d){ return d["Year"];});
```

and also

```
var yearDimension = data.dimension(function(d){ return (String(d["Year"]));});
```

but this set up generated this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ordinal' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error in declaring the csv file.

Problem solved here: https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/issues/127